# Pandas Dataframe matching Dates between rows

Tags: python, pandas

```
REF         FROM_DATE               EXEMPT_FROM
10001033    2017-07-11 00:00:00     2017-07-11 00:00:00
10001033    2017-07-11 00:00:00     2017-08-10 00:00:00
10001033    2017-07-11 00:00:00     2018-04-01 00:00:00
10001769    2018-05-15 00:00:00     2016-07-15 00:00:00
10001769    2018-05-15 00:00:00     2018-01-03 00:00:00
10001769    2018-05-15 00:00:00     2018-05-15 00:00:00
10001769    2018-05-15 00:00:00     2018-06-14 00:00:00
```

I have the above data frame and I would like to be able to count the number of Unique REFs whose first row From_DATE does not match its first row Exempt_FROM.

For example the first REF number 10001033 FROM_DATE and EXEMPT_FROM match but the second REF 10001769 do not. What might be the best approach?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: provide sample data in text format, otherwise it's not easy to help

Comment: So far I have tried,                                            data[(data['EXEMPT_FROM'] != data['FROM_DATE'])].unique()

Comment: @Yuca hope that helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, this is what you want

```
A = df.groupby('REF').first()
A.FROM_DATE == A.EXEMPT_FROM
```

Output:

```
REF
10001033     True
10001769    False
```

If you want to know how many times you have the desired match, apply `sum`

```
sum(A.FROM_DATE == A.EXEMPT_FROM)
```